# how to make joomla 3 custom components menu type hierarchical (like in joomla 1.5)

Tags: components, joomla3.0, menu-items

I am upgrading an old Joomla 1.5 component to Joomla 3.0. When I try to add Joomla component in old system to menu, I get these selections:
[image]

But when I try to add my new component to menu, and write xml files in template catalogs, as described in [Joomla tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Example_of_menu_parameters_and_stylesheets), I get this (flat, repeating menu items):

[image]

What am I missing? Component works well under new platform, but I guess some xml structure should be written for menu structure.

Comment: Repeating item problem was solved - closing slash before closing <metadata> was absent and copied into every xml file, now I can see different titles and descriptions, but help on hierarchy is still needed. The corrected file looks:                                   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
 <layout title="COM_QUOTES_PROJECTS_DETAILS_TITLE">
  <message><![CDATA[COM_QUOTES_PROJECTS_DETAILS_DESC]]></message>
 </layout>
</metadata>